# Hadoop Hortonworks servers down

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

I installed Hortonworks Hadoop system on my MacBook yesterday. Everything was fine, servers were working but I turned off and turn on again Virtual box today and try to connect Hadoop I saw so many servers are not working(MapReduce, Hive Yarn..).

It might be a silly question but I am so new. Why happened? When I turn on the virtual box Do I have to wait to see anything?

Here is the picture of my Dashboard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is OK then probably you should check your virtual programs (virtual box or VMWare).

Virtual box is slower than VMWare. When you try to connect Hadoop database and you should see the screen that says you can go http://127.0.... then you can connect otherwise you can see your systems are down.